# Why is INET Aodv routing not working in OMNeT++?

Tags: omnet++, inet

I was following the [INET Wireless Tutorial](https://inet.omnetpp.org/docs/tutorials/wireless/doc/index.html), but when I reached [step 10](https://inet.omnetpp.org/docs/tutorials/wireless/doc/step10.html), which is configuring Aodv routing protocol, it doesn't work.

I also followed [this guide](https://inet.omnetpp.org/docs/showcases/routing/manet/doc/index.html) on manet routing protocols successfully: the three routing protocols worked. But in the step 10 of the Wireless Tutorial it doesn't work.

In the simulation, it starts ok and the first route is created, allowing the transmission of packets

[image]

But when hostR1 gets out of the transmission range of hostA and hostB, the new route through hostR2 and hostR3 doesn't set up.

[image]

I was typing the code, but then I copied and pasted it just to make sure it was right, but it still doesn't work. The code is here: [omnet.ini](https://inet.omnetpp.org/docs/_downloads/omnetpp44.ini), [WirelessA.ned](https://inet.omnetpp.org/docs/_downloads/WirelessA.ned), [WirelessB.ned](https://inet.omnetpp.org/docs/_downloads/WirelessB.ned)

The part where it configures Aodv is this

```
[Config Wireless10]
description = Configuring ad-hoc routing (AODV)
extends = Wireless09

*.configurator.addStaticRoutes = false

*.host*.typename = "AodvRouter"

*.hostB.wlan[0].radio.displayCommunicationRange = true

*.visualizer.dataLinkVisualizer.packetFilter = "AODV*"
```

Can anyone tell me if I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to compare your omnetpp.ini to the file in the tutorial sources to see any differences. Seeing the effect I suspect that the MAC layer acknowledgement is not turned on (check Config Wireless06 & 07), which means that the routing protocol cannot detect a when a link broke, which means it will not create new routes either.